# Insert into one column from another table WITHOUT setting the other columns on null

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert

I have a question concering the INSERT INTO command. 
My problem is that I want to insert the primary key from one table into another. But the issue is that it automatically sets the other columns on `NULL` after using the command:
`INSERT INTO e_p_employee(p_person_p_SVNR) SELECT p_SVNR FROM p_person`

Now my question is, is there any possibility that I can get my `p_SVNR`values into `p_Person_p_SVNR` without having all the other column values set to `NULL`?

Using a join will not work, since `e_p_employee` inherits from `p_person`
[Click here to see the model.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZFl2.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are actually using.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? NULL means there is no value known which is actually true. you can also insert alot of blanks and 0's instead but that doesn't seem like a good idea either. you need to rethink your structure or the process of inserting data i think. the whole idea of foreign keys and dependence is that you need there to be a person before you can make that person into an employee.

Comment: But the thing is that I only want to insert into ONE column without affecting the others at all, because I already have data for e_Salary, etc. inserted.. Now I want to get the p_SVNR into p_Person_p_SVNR that I can join these two tables later on.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use an UPDATE not an insert. UPDATE will update certain columns of an existing where insert will create a new row.

Comment: But there is no possibility to do the UPDATE without any JOIN right? Or is there?

Comment: When the updated value is based on data in the updated record, there is no need to JOIN. Joining tables comes in handy when the updated data is received from another table, or is a manipulation on data from another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting a primary key creates a new record. **In the new record each field receives** the Value inserted, or **it's default value**, witch could be Null, or another value of the field's data type.
**You can't create a record, and have some of it's fields *not there***...